# vcr2015 won't install

Tags: 16.04, wine, games, playonlinux, winetricks

When I try to run vcr2015 (x86 version) I get this error:

```
elijah$ wine ./vc_redist.x86.exe
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationToken QueryInformationToken( ..., TokenElevation, ...) semi-stub
err:ole:CoInitializeEx Attempt to change threading model of this apartment from multi-threaded to apartment threaded
err:ole:apartment_getclassobject DllGetClassObject returned error 0x80040111
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {f5078f1b-c551-11d3-89b9-0000f81fe221} could be created for context 0x1
```

I tried creating and running it in a 32-bit wineprefix and i get this, an even bigger error:

```
elijah$ env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wine32 wine ./vc_redist.x86.exe 
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationToken QueryInformationToken( ..., TokenElevation, ...) semi-stub
err:ole:CoInitializeEx Attempt to change threading model of this apartment from multi-threaded to apartment threaded
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationToken QueryInformationToken( ..., TokenElevation, ...) semi-stub
err:ole:CoInitializeEx Attempt to change threading model of this apartment from multi-threaded to apartment threaded
fixme:advapi:DecryptFileW (L"C:\\users\\elijah\\Temp\\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}\\", 00000000): stub
```

any help would be appreciated.

(also, I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 xenial with my wine config set to windows 8)

[edit]
I need vcr2015 to install the BIGFOOT game.